# drush - which folder for install on VPS / root server (newbie)

Tags: 7, users, drush, installation

good evening,

new to drupal - I want to install drush on my linux root-server, which  **runs OpenSuse Linux** my friend does the root adminstration.

What is aimed: i want to work on all my drupal domains - but i guess that i do not need root access. Can anyone please tell me which folder I should use to install drush?

Do you need to have my file structure? Well if so, i  can give you later this week.

Well a friend told me to take `$HOME/local/drush,` but cant we put it anywhere;
we just need to make sure that drush is in our $PATH. See the README.

or what is with this hint top take the domain path like so

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com and echo $HOME gives me /root.
```

So would I create a 'local' directory in /root and install drush there

so the path would be `/local/drush/drush.php?`
I am not just asking from a drush point of view but also from a server file structure point of view ie that I think I am not allowed to upload stuff to some server directories.

But wait - i do not want to have all root rights - is this doable?!
Can i install drush into the www-directory where all the domains are rooted!?

Thanks for any and all help - it will be greatly appreciated as allways. 
zero-your drupalnovice

hi there **just an update**:

if someone wants to update the sites trough the terminal?

in that case:

I don't think it's matter where we put it, we could put it in the root if we'd like, once installed after pear-chanell....

http://drupal.org/project/drush

we can update any site on our

srv/www/htdocs

we just have  to get inside the htdocs/site1 and type drush sm update
do our things and get into our new site htdocs/site2 and do whatever we want to do there with drush too.

and the best thing is: one install works on all our sites.

that rocks yeah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Drush in the folder of your choice. Preferably outside www-directory. But make sure the drush command is executable.

To make drush command executable on all domains just create a symlink to drush.
For e.g

$ ln -s /path/to/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush

Answer (score 5):

You didn't say much about the distribution you're using. but i would suggest searching for a package for your Linux distribution. Installing it that way usually is the safest and easiest. There is one for Debian/Ubuntu and Gentoo as far as i know.

Comment: Side note: Using pear to install is dead simple.  :) See http://drupal.org/project/drush

Comment: Hi you both: my linux root-server, which  **runs OpenSuse Linux** thx for the hints regarding pear!!